# 3d physics engine for javascript that supports gyroscopic force

Tags: javascript, 3d

Im looking for a 3d physics engine that natively supports simulating the gyroscopic resistance force acting upon an object in rotational motion. Also, between physijs, cannon, ammo, and bullet, which physics engine would you recommend to be the most accurate?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure but I feel like it depends on what device your targeting. If you're going for Windows RunTime or Windows Phone, you need to use Microsoft APIs. Same story for Apple or Android. So you should research what APIs each respective platform offers.

You might have to calculate the acceleration yourself. It'd be vectors. I'm not too experienced with 3D so someone else will have to help you there.

In regards to accuracy, you're going to have to benchmark that yourself. If that's a huge concern that is. It may be that you don't want a super accurate engine because that means there are more calculations (possibly) and therefore it could be more resource intensive. Since you mentioned gyroscopes, I am under the impression this is a mobile game. Therefore, you'll want something that gives you the most FPS. If necessary, hook your own math into the engine for things you don't like. In my opinion, it's better to write something that is optimized ahead of time rather than wasting time going back and fixing things. But that's my opinion, and it may not be the opinion of more experienced programmers.

I think the best option is to use the one that appeals to you most. Just check out some reviews and see what people have to say about the particular engine. Is it sloppy? Is it full of math errors? Then it's probably not for you. However, if people recommend it but you hate the syntax, why use it?

Good luck!

Comment: My apologies, I don't think I was very clear about my question. I have found API's that can work with gyroscopic sensors, however I am looking for a physics simulation engine that supports simulating the gyroscopic resistance force of a rotating object. Thanks!

Comment: Oh sorry. I don't know :P Definitely want to use a library for that one. Good luck on your search!

Answer (score 0):

Newton Game Dynamics has a gyroscopic forces option:
http://newtondynamics.com/wiki/index.php5?title=NewtonBodyCoriolisForcesMode

It is turned off by default but apparently you can turn it on if you wish.